# update form returns blank page

Tags: php, mysql

i have developed a form to update several fields in a table but upon submission it returns an clear page. here is the code that i am using for submission.

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form")) {

    $doa_bits = explode('/', $_POST['doa']);

  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tbl_personalinjury SET role=%s, driverNo=%s, clientName=%s, address=%s, residedYrs=%s, cntctSolicitor=%s, telephoneHome=%s, telephoneMobile=%s, time=%s, time2=%s, dobDay=%s, dobMonth=%s, dobYear=%s, maritalStatus=%s, job=%s, niNo=%s, doaDay=%s, doaMonth=%s, doaYear=%s, time3=%s, time4=%s, weather=%s, location=%s, policeDetail=%s, accidentDetail=%s, blame=%s, witnessDetail=%s, dName=%s, dAdd=%s, dvMake=%s, dvModel=%s, dReg=%s, dInsurance=%s, tName=%s, tAdd=%s, tvMake=%s, tvModel=%s, tReg=%s, tInsurance=%s, seatbelt=%s, injuries=%s, injuries2=%s, recover=%s, timeoff=%s, loss=%s, expenses=%s, sports=%s, hospital=%s, gpName=%s, gpAddress=%s WHERE id=$client_id",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['role'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['driverNo'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['clientName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['residedYrs'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cntctSolicitor'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['telephoneHome'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['telephoneMobile'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['time'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['time2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dobDay'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dobMonth'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dobYr'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['maritalStatus'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['job'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['niNo'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($doa_bits[0], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($doa_bits[1], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($doa_bits[2], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['time3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['time4'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['weather'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['location'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['policeDetail'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['accidentDetail'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['blame'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['witnessDetail'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dAdd'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dvMake'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dvModel'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dReg'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dInsurance'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tAdd'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tvMake'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tvModel'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tReg'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tInsurance'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['seatbelt'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['injuries'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['injuries2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['recover'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['timeoff'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['loss'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['expenses'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['sports'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['hospital'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['gpName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['gpAddress'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['driverNo'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_speedycms, $speedycms);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $speedycms) or die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database_speedycms, $speedycms);
$query_accident = "SELECT * FROM tbl_personalinjury WHERE id=$client_id";
$accident = mysql_query($query_accident, $speedycms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_accident = mysql_fetch_assoc($accident);
$totalRows_accident = mysql_num_rows($accident);
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Are you having issues with the SQL call or are you expecting something to be printed on the page, if so you need to `print`. something out

Comment: im expecting something to be printed on the page

Comment: The only thing I see that could generate output assuming errors are disabled is `or die(mysql_error())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not invoking any functions that output text. Therefore, the page is blank. Simple as that.

And judging from the fact that the page is blank, it'd be safe to assume that your query successfully executed because it didn't run `die(mysql_error())`, which would've outputted an error message if there was an error.